# Texture coordinate and displacement modifier

Tags: texturing, modifiers, texture-coordinates

I am creating world using texture coordinate node and displacement modifier on plane. But it doesn't work until I apply the displacement modifier. Why does that happen? How to avoid that? Here are the nodes:
Before apply:[image]

[image]

Comment: This does look like a bug. I'm having trouble reproducing it consistently. Intermittently, it happens when Midlevel is set to 0, and for me, always, when the texture space is changed to global, and then back again. The effect disappears if the file is reverted. If you can reproduce it on several builds, and helpfully track it down to a particular sequence of events, it's reportable.

Answer (score 2):

I messed around a bit with vector math and found a quick fix:

By subtracting the object's location from the geometry's position output, you can get the same results, regardless of where the object is in the scene. You can then tweak the vector with a vector math node to perfect the result (scaling the object vertically might mess the math up a bit though).

I'm guessing blender hasn't yet implemented your approach with modifiers. In the first image, you can see the original material with the displace modifier applied. The second image is my suggested fix.

[image: texture coordinates based]

[image: geometry based]

Happy blending!